# Flutter DataTable cell text not wrapping inside of a row

Tags: flutter, text, datatable, row, word-wrap

I'm trying to put a dataTable in a row widget, but I lose the text wrapping in the individual cells when I do that. 
This code works correctly:

```
  class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  Testing({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDataTableState createState() => _MyDataTableState();
}

class _MyDataTableState extends State<Testing> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DataTable"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(        <-- Text wrapping goes away when wrapped in a Row()
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: DataTable(
          // columnSpacing: 100,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Container(
                width: 100,
                child: Text('Item Code'),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Stock Item'),
            ),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text('Yup.  text.'),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                      'This is a really long text. It\'s supposed to be long so that I can figure out what in the hell is happening to the ability to have the text wrap in this datacell.  So far, I haven\'t been able to figure it out.'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to preserve the text wrapping inherent in a DataTable when wrapped in a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded` too.

```
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  Testing({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDataTableState createState() => _MyDataTableState();
}

class _MyDataTableState extends State<Testing> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DataTable"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          //TODO: use Expanded here
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: DataTable(
                // columnSpacing: 100,
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Text('Item Code'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Stock Item'),
                  ),
                ],
                rows: [
                  DataRow(
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(
                        Text('Yup.  text.'),
                      ),
                      DataCell(
                        Text(
                            'This is a really long text. It\'s supposed to be long so that I can figure out what in the hell is happening to the ability to have the text wrap in this datacell.  So far, I haven\'t been able to figure it out.'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Datatable definitely does wrap text.  The example I provided wraps the text...until you put it in a row.

Comment: @WilliamTerrill Corrected the answer :)

Comment: This code is doing the same thing that the code I pasted is doing. It wraps the text in the same way.  The problem that I'm having is when I wrap the body in a Row() widget, the wrapping goes away. DataTable and Table both wrap when not in Row()... but I couldn't get your code to render when I wrapped your line: "body: SingleChildScrollView(" in a Row() widget. (which is the problem that I'm having.)

Comment: @WilliamTerrill Ok. Then try using `Expanded` inside `Row`

Comment: @WilliamTerrill Pls post code which causes the issue

Comment: I've noted it in the original code with this line: "<-- Text wrapping goes away when wrapped in a Row()"  That, also, is the same line as what you have. "body: SingleChildScrollView( "  So, just take your code and wrap that line in a Row()

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you very much for working with me!

Answer (score 2):

I have been stuck on a similar problem since this morning.

For me, the DataColumn "label" Text wasn't wrapping. Although the text in the DataRow cell was wrapping just fine

After trying multiple variations, this is what worked for me.
Put the label text inside **Expanded** and set **softWrap** text property to true

```
       DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
            label: Expanded(
          child: Text(
            "Very long text goes here",
            softWrap: true,
          ),
        )),
      ],
      rows: [],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens because of how `Row` naturally works. It takes as much as available horizontal axis. Although the `mainAxisSize` can be configured(min or max) according to the children, `DataTable` doesn't have initial width therefore resulting `Text` not being wrapped.

For quick fix you can wrap the `Data Table` in `Container` and give it a const width.

**Quick test on DartPad:** https://dartpad.dev/a664a29160b6e0443e9ca3bf28d5ec69

**Snippet:**

```
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  Testing({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDataTableState createState() => _MyDataTableState();
}

class _MyDataTableState extends State<Testing> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DataTable"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300, // Give the DataTable a const width.
            child: DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                  label: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Text('Item Code'),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('Stock Item'),
                ),
              ],
              rows: [
                DataRow(
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text('Yup.  text.'),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Wrap(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              'This is a really long text. It\'s supposed to be long so that I can figure out what in the hell is happening to the ability to have the text wrap in this datacell.  So far, I haven\'t been able to figure it out.')
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep it as responsive as possible, so I'm trying not to add fixed width. (unless there is no other solution)

Comment: Basically the solution by @Crazy Lazy Cat is the next solution beside giving an "indefinite size Widget" a const size inside Row or Column. What you have to learn is, Row and Column don't have a definite size (width or height) naturally, therefore you can't put Widgets that don't have natural constraint size as the children of Row and Column. So the solution is: Either put a const size for the children or wrap it inside Expanded widget because by wrapping it inside Expanded, Flutter knows how much that widget should be drawn.

Comment: @FederickJonathan this works fine only with one row. When you duplicate the row in your example the second row is painted on top of some contents of the first row...